# Corda NodeDriver v3 logging

Tags: corda

Starting from V3 the NodeDriver builds a standard output & error logfile for each node instead of printing all logs in the console. Is there still a possibility to have the logging in the console too? And are there any other possibilities regarding NodeDriver logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the NodeDriver with `startNodesInProcess = true` runs all the nodes in the same process, but also logs every Node output in the console window again.